# How do I solve postman and browser clients both giving empty curly braces in array [{}] in JSON on HTTP Methods Problem?

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

When I am trying to access data from my MySQL DB codedecode using HTTP Get Method either on browser client or postman client there is empty curly braces in array [{}] is shown. But, I have data into my database. I have attached all my code including the dependencies of my Pom.xml and and my application props for my project.

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.1</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.codedecode</groupId>
<artifactId>CodeDecodeCRUD</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>CodeDecodeCRUD</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot and Hibernate</description>
<properties>
    <java.version>17</java.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
    <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
    <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <excludes>
            <exclude>
                <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            </exclude>
        </excludes>
        </configuration>
     </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

**Spring Container**

```
package com.codedecode.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class CodeDecodeCrudApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(CodeDecodeCrudApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

**Employee Rest Controller**

```
package com.codedecode.demo.controller;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.codedecode.demo.entity.Employee;
import com.codedecode.demo.repos.EmployeeCrudRepo;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/code")
public class EmployeeController {

    @Autowired
    EmployeeCrudRepo empCrud;
    
    @GetMapping("/getall")
    public List<Employee> getAllEmployees() {
        System.out.println("getting all employees");
    return empCrud.findAll();
    }   
}
```

**Employee Entity**

```
package com.codedecode.demo.entity;

import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.GenerationType;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.Table;

import lombok.Data;

@Entity
@Table(name = "emp")
@Data
public class Employee {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    
    private String name;
}
```

**Employee CRUD Repository**

```
package com.codedecode.demo.repos;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.codedecode.demo.entity.Employee;

@Repository
public interface EmployeeCrudRepo extends JpaRepository<Employee, Long>{    
    
}
```

**application.properties**

```
#server.port=9090
#spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/codedecode?useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
#spring.jpa.show-sql=true
#spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
```

I am using, MySQL v8.0.33, Spring v3.1.1, Java v17, STS v4, lombok v1.18.28

I tried checking the cofiguration of my MySQL DB, but everything working fine. Tables are created when the server runs.

I tried rechecking my code and all the dependencies but unable to find any issue.

Comment: Hello, please add no-args constructor to the entity class. Use Lombok @NoArgsConstructor annotation. This is needed for Hibernate to correctly map the results of the query to the entity object.

Comment: Good Evening everyone, Thank you for your responses but I resolved my issue with STS v4 and Spring 2.7.13 will also check it with Spring v3.1.1. But, I am happy that I am getting help from the best brains in the world. Thank you for your support and for considering my issue worth resolving it means a lot to me. This is the first time I have asked a question on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few things you can check to troubleshoot the issue:

1. Database Connectivity:

   - Ensure that your MySQL server is up and running.
   - Verify that the database (`codedecode`) exists and is accessible with the provided credentials (`root/root`).
   - Check the `emp` table in the `codedecode` database and ensure it contains data.
2. Entity Mapping:

   - Verify that the `Employee` entity class (`com.codedecode.demo.entity.Employee`) is correctly mapped to the `emp` table in the database.
   - Check that the column names in the entity match the column names in the database table (`id`, `name`).
   - Ensure that the `@Entity`, `@Table`, and `@Data` annotations are imported from the correct packages (`jakarta.persistence.*` and `lombok.*`).
3. Repository Configuration:

   - Confirm that the `EmployeeCrudRepo` interface (`com.codedecode.demo.repos.EmployeeCrudRepo`) is correctly extending `JpaRepository`.
   - Check that the repository interface is scanned by Spring by ensuring it is in a package covered by component scanning or explicitly configured as a repository.
4. Application Configuration:

   - Make sure that the `application.properties` file is located in the correct directory (`src/main/resources`) and is being picked up by the application.
   - Check that the MySQL JDBC driver (`mysql-connector-java`) is being resolved correctly by Maven and included in the classpath.
   - Verify that the `spring.datasource.url`, `spring.datasource.username`, and `spring.datasource.password` properties are correctly configured to connect to your MySQL server.
5. Logging and Debugging:

   - Enable debug logging in your Spring Boot application by adding the following line to `application.properties`:

     ```
     logging.level.org.springframework=DEBUG
     ```
   - Review the logs during application startup to ensure that the database connection is being established and the entities are being mapped correctly.
   - Check for any error messages or warnings related to database connectivity, entity mapping, or repository configuration.

By reviewing these aspects, you should be able to identify the issue causing the empty JSON response. Additionally, examining the application logs and any error messages can provide valuable insights into the problem.

Comment: Hi Md Saif! thank you for your response. I have checked all the points you have mentioned, but everything seems fine.  The name attribute I am giving from Postman in JSON is not saving in the DB but only the key which is autogenerated gets saved. Even I use save&flush also, but the result is the same data not saving in DB and [{}] empty curly braces in Postman. Don't know what I am doing wrong that's why I posted the question on Stack Overflow. Please help me with this issue. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! 

Your answer appears likely to have been written (entirely or partially) by AI (e.g., ChatGPT). A heads-up that [posting AI-generated content is not allowed here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If you used an AI tool to assist with any answer, I would encourage you to delete it.

We do hope you'll continue to be a part of our community and contribute with *your own*, quality posts in the future. Thanks!

Comment: **Readers should review this answer carefully and critically, as AI-generated information often contains fundamental errors and misinformation.** If you observe quality issues and/or have reason to believe that this answer was generated by AI, please leave feedback accordingly.

Comment: Good Evening @NotTheDr01ds sir, I am not using any AI Tool to generate this comment I swear. And, never will, I can assure you that. Don't worry I am still dependent on myself and my own decision, not some AI Tool to guide me. Because humans are always the best thinkers. And, you are here before me, you are my seniors and I respect you all. So I can never use AI to disrespect you all. You guys are the best brains in all over the world from whom I can learn a lot. Thank You!

Comment: @FaizAhmadKhan Apologies for any confusion - I am referring to *this answer* (which you didn't write) as being likely AI.  I see that *your* answer below is genuine, and I upvoted it yesterday.  I also replied back to the person who commented on it to try to point out *their* mistake in misunderstanding your question.  Don't worry - I see that you are genuine!